# Differentiate between same strings with different punctuation in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ program to count the frequency of a word occurring in a text file. I am using the `isalpha` function to separate the words, but `isalpha` does not differentiate between same strings having different punctuation.

For example: "I own a company. In my company, there are 200 employees. I love my company."
In the above sentence it gives count of company as 3
How do I make it to differentiate the count like:

```
company 1
company, 1
company. 1
```

The loop which does the counting:

```
while(!isalpha(c) && !in.eof())
{
    c = in.get();
}

while(isalpha(c))
{
    out.push_back(tolower(c));
    c = in.get();
}
```

where 'out' is a string, 'in' is an istream value and c is a char.

[EDIT] Got Solution

```
while(!isalpha(c) && !ispunct(c) !in.eof())
{
    c = in.get();
}

while(isalpha(c) || ispunct(c))
{
    out.push_back(tolower(c));
    c = in.get();
}
```

Comment: Recheck and rethink the logic of the `while` conditions.

Comment: Hello, @user -- is this a homework question? We *do* help with homework sometimes, but it is good for us to know if that is the case.

Comment: no Rob, this is just me exploring C++, I wanted someone to brainstorm. Thanks anyways, figured out the solution and have posted for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought your way was better (I would expect company to have a count of 3).

But if you want to separate words and punctuation is significant, then use isspace() as a separator.

Note: The standard stream >> operator already does this for you.

```
std::string  word;
in >> word;
std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Comment: so instead of isalpha in both the while loops you want me to use isspace?

Comment: @user1035927: Yep (and reverse the not condition).

Comment: Ok got the solution, I used ispunct instead with an or condition:           Thanks for all your help....